# Android Firebase is not able to create new user using email and password

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am hoping that someone can help me. Below is my code to create a new new user with email and password but for some reason it is not able to create a new user, I tried many differenet approaches but cannot seem to find out why it is not able create a new user.

```
package com.example.splitit

import android.content.Intent
import android.graphics.Typeface
import android.os.Bundle
import android.text.Spannable
import android.text.SpannableString
import android.text.style.StyleSpan
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.EditText
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.activity.enableEdgeToEdge
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import com.example.splitit.databinding.ActivitySignupBinding
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase

class signup : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var fullName: EditText
    private lateinit var signupemail: EditText
    private lateinit var signuppassword: EditText
    private lateinit var signuppasswordconfrm: EditText
    private lateinit var signupbtn: Button
    private lateinit var database: FirebaseDatabase
    private lateinit var reference: DatabaseReference
    private lateinit var auth: FirebaseAuth

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        val binding: ActivitySignupBinding by lazy {
            ActivitySignupBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        }
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        enableEdgeToEdge()
        setContentView(binding.root)
        val splitOnboardText = "\$plitIt"
        val spanableString = SpannableString(splitOnboardText)
        val startIndex = spanableString.indexOf("It")
        val endIndex = startIndex + "It".length
        spanableString.setSpan(
            StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD),
            startIndex,
            endIndex,
            Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE
        )
        val textSplitIt = binding.splititSignup
        textSplitIt.text = spanableString

        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()

        fullName = binding.editTextTextSignup
        signupemail = binding.editTextTextEmailAddressSignup
        signuppassword = binding.editTextNumberPasswordSignUp
        signuppasswordconfrm = binding.editTextNumberConfirmPasswordSignUp
        signupbtn = binding.signupBtn

        signupbtn.setOnClickListener {
            database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
            reference = database.getReference("users")

            val name = fullName.text.toString()
            val emailSignup = signupemail.text.toString()
            val passwordSignup = signuppassword.text.toString()
            val passwordConfirmSignup = signuppasswordconfrm.text.toString()

            if (name.isEmpty() || emailSignup.isEmpty() || passwordSignup.isEmpty() || passwordConfirmSignup.isEmpty()) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter all the fields", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            } else if (passwordSignup != passwordConfirmSignup) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Repeat Password must be same", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            } else {
                auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(emailSignup, passwordSignup)
                    .addOnCompleteListener(this) { task ->
                        if (task.isSuccessful) {
                            Toast.makeText(
                                this,
                                "Successfully added to authentication",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                            ).show()
                            val intent = Intent(this, login::class.java)
                            startActivity(intent)
                        } else {
                            Log.e("FirebaseAuth", "Registration failed", task.exception)
                            Toast.makeText(
                                this,
                                "Registraion Failed : ${task.exception?.message}",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                            ).show()
                        }
                    }
//                val helperClass = HelperClass(name,emailSignup,passwordSignup,passwordConfirmSignup)
//                reference.child(name).setValue(helperClass)
//
//                Toast.makeText(this, "You have signed up successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
//                val intent = Intent(this,login::class.java)
//                startActivity(intent)
            }


        }

    }
}
```

I tried what the error might be making a toast but it is not showing anything
I even tried logging the error, but it only says Creating user with example@gmail.com with empty reCAPTCHA token

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding what the problem is. What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: Since you're using Kotlin, I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-authenticate-to-firebase-using-email-and-password-in-jetpack-compose-bd70ca56ea91) will help. Here is the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/FirebaseSignInWithEmailAndPassword).